# Is it safe to omit the INNER keyword if I explicitly want to INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

It’s not that important (please take note), but it’s a syntactical particularity and it’s about portability, and I didn’t find a question (or answer) quoting reliable resources or specifications, so I’m curious:

**Is it *safe* to omit the `INNER` keyword if I explicitly want to `INNER JOIN`?**

By “safe” I mean:

- It will work in both SQL Server 2000 and 2016.
- It will work in any other SQL flavor without the `FROM` clause needing adjustment.
- Its backward and forward compatibility is not just a sure bet.
- Its reliability is backed by being standard compliant.

Regarding `INNER`, [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) (for versions 2005 through 2014) say:

> When no join type is specified, this is the default.

The [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) implicitly notes:

> `[ INNER ] JOIN`

I didn’t find a corresponding statement in the [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) nor while searching the web for Oracle or ANSI/ISO SQL, the latter being of particular interest.

Comment: The `inner` key word is optional in all databases that I can think of, with the exception of MS Access.  Compatibility with MS Access is way, way down on my list of priorities, so I often just go for less typing.

Comment: I personally always type `INNER JOIN` when I intend an inner join even though it isn't required. Just reads easiers and springs right in the eye what you mean.

Comment: I personally _never_ type `INNER` (or `OUTER`) to reduce the noise when reading a SQL statement.

Answer (score 6):

The `INNER`/`OUTER` designations for `JOIN`s are a form of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). A `JOIN` implies that it is `INNER` by default. Likewise, `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` imply `OUTER` by default. This is a SQL universal, as far as I know.

Comment: Nice, I didn’t know there was a implication for `OUTER` too, thank you. Anyhow, backing the common assumption that it’s “a SQL universal” was my primary intent. Can you think of any primary sources?

Comment: This can be seen best by looking at their functions. `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `FULL` can only apply to `OUTER JOIN`s since `INNER` and `CROSS JOIN`s produce a result that only includes the items that appear in both tables (according to their criteria). Thus, `FULL JOIN` doesn't need to specify `OUTER`. That a basic `JOIN` implies `INNER` is just convention, but it is accepted everywhere SQL is served...

Comment: @SQLTactics in your answer you say that specifying the INNER designation for JOIN is syntactic sugar, but in your comment you say it's a convention that is just accepted everywhere. is it part of the standard or not, according to you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the SQL standard defines the keyword `INNER` (or `OUTER`) as *optional*.

A JOIN is defined like this:

```
<qualified join> ::=
     { <table reference> | <partitioned join table> }
     [ <join type> ] JOIN
     { <table reference> | <partitioned join table> }
     <join specification>
```

As you can see `<join type>` is optional (because it's in square brackets) and is defined as:

```
<join type> ::=
    INNER
    | <outer join type> [ OUTER ]

<outer join type> ::=
    LEFT
    | RIGHT
```

Comment: That’s about the standard definition I couldn’t find, thanks. Is there a reliable source for it, or a way to look up this ANSI/ISO excerpt?